# Where can I ask "What library can I use to do X?"

Tags: support, site-recommendation

"What library can I use to do X?" type of questions are not welcome on Stack Overflow, right?

Even if they are not welcome on SO proper, is there any other SE board where I could ask such questions?

Comment: It might be (and "might" is important here) a fit for the Software Recommendations SE that is currently in beta. But make sure to carefully read through their help center first. I don't participate, so I am not 100% certain: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: That seems like it might be the right one. Let me try.

Comment: You might want to read through this as well: http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/8/is-it-alright-to-ask-for-programming-tools

Comment: Emphasis on "***might***". Several moderators will come to your house at night and give you an atomic wedgie if you don't read the rules.

Comment: And if that *might* becomes a "I'll try" be sure you read [What is required for a question to contain “enough information”?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information)

Comment: And if all those comments didn't scare you yet ..... BOOOOOO

Comment: [OK, I have done it.](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2206/calendar-library-with-recurring-events-exceptions-etc)

Comment: One of youse guys, @Bart or wilx, should post an answer here.

Comment: If you're looking for a particular library for a specific language, you might try the chat-room for that language (if that sort of question is acceptable).

Comment: http://slant.co